# How to gather all values of specific rows in each sheets?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am new to python, and I have no idea how to gather all needed value to multiple list. For example, I need all the row values of

```
df["notes"] == 0.5
```

[image: Excel]

so I write some codes to print specific values(e.g. 1.322921452, 0.838709677,....,0.749, 1.1827...,0.9921, 0.92473...)
But the current code print all the sheets of 0.5 values, I need to separate them sheet by sheet into whatever dataframe or list.
This is my current code

```
df_ls = [pd.DataFrame() for i in range(6)]

a = []


for i in range(5):
    for j in (range(40)):
        df = pd.read_excel("norm.xlsx",sheet_name = i) 
        for note in range(0, len(df["notes"])):
            if df["notes"][note] == 0.5:
                value = df.iloc[note, j+1]
```

I expect the list would be like

```
sheet1 = [1.322921452, 0.838709677...]
sheet2 = [0.534344,0.9484...]
.
.
.
sheet5 = [0.243,0.3331155]
```

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: If you have a DataFrame like the sheet in the screenshot, where the name of the first column is `notes` and subsequent columns are labeled by ascending non-negative integers, getting a DataFrame of all columns for rows where the value in `notes` is 0.5 is `df.query("notes == .5")` or `df[df['notes'] == .5]`

Comment: Ok! Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern: `read_csv` with `sheet_name=None` load all sheets into a dictionary. Filter each dataframe with your condition then concat them into a new dataframe:

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('norm.xlsx', sheet_name=None)
data = {}
for sheet, df in dfs.items():
    data[sheet] = df.loc[df['notes'] == 0.5]
df = pd.concat(data)
```

Output:

```
# Sample
>>> df
          notes   0
Sheet1 0    0.5   1
       1    0.5   2
       2    0.5   3
Sheet2 0    0.5  11
       1    0.5  12
       2    0.5  13
```

How to use the dataframe:

```
>>> df.loc['Sheet1']
   notes  0
0    0.5  1
1    0.5  2
2    0.5  3
```

Comment: Hey, it's nice to see all the values collecting into every single dataframe from each sheet. But I'm wondering how to collect them independently. For example, sheet1 = [0.254,0.2342] 、sheet2 = [0.5454,0.231]....sheet5 = [0.9282,0.3232].